# Difference between Copy-On-Write and Compare-Then-Swap?

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, concurrency, thread-safety

I am learning about Java Concurrent Collections (`java.util.concurrent`) and the underlying techniques used. I stumbled upon Copy-On-Write and Compare-And-Swap.

I cannot quite understand what is the difference between those two. Or are both somehow used together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are concurrent collections, but they use different mechanisms.

Copy-on-write collections use an effectively immutable array, and any modification creates a new array. They use synchronization briefly, during the creation of the new array. They are good if reads greatly predominate write operations.

Conversely, some other concurrent collections use Compare-And-Swap (so called CAS) mechanism for concurrency control. That is built based on low level CPU instructions which is a fundamental improvement on traditional synchronization.

Comment: I think it would not be correct to say that "both are concurrent collection". They are certainly different techniques to implement thread safety and atomicity of operations. CopyOnWriteArrayList is definitely a concrete implementation of Collection.

Answer (score 0):

A very commonly occurring patterns in programs and concurrent algorithms is the "check then act" in compare and swap the java.util.concurrent.atomic package provide atomic operation which is non blocking.

```
private AtomicBoolean locked = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    public boolean lock() {
        return locked.compareAndSet(false, true);
    }
```

Internally it will check old value and if not changed update with new value.
In Other case  **CopyOnWriteArrayListlike**  a thread-safe variant of java.util.ArrayList in which all mutative operations add and set  and so on are implemented by making a fresh copy of the underlying array.